# ModuleNotFoundError in Python again

Tags: python, packaging, modulenotfounderror

apparantly I simply just don't get packaging in Python, `ModuleNotFoundError`s are my bane.

I recently published a small package on pypi: [rdfdf](https://github.com/lu-pl/rdfdf). `from rdfdf import DFGraphConverter` gives me the dreaded `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'` and I just don't get it, `helpers` has an `__init__.py` file so it should be visible as a subpackage.

Help is much need and much appreciated.

Edit:

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/projects/python-projects/cortab/cortab/transformation.py", line 4, in <module>
    from rdfdf import DFGraphConverter
  File "/home/user/environments/cortab/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rdfdf.py", line 7, in <module>
    from helpers.rdfdf_utils import anaphoric
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'
```

Comment: (1) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question. (2) Where is the main script located with which you start the program?

Comment: Thanks for answering! I installed the package from pypi and importing the package errors even in a fresh Python shell. The link provided points to the code, I would appreciate it if you could have a look.

Comment: I don't see anything in your poetry/pyproject files which tell the installation what you want to package. I'm not familiar with poetry, but the cause is `helpers` not being installed (you can download what you [uploaded on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/rdfdf/#files) to see that `helpers` is not part of it).

Comment: btw, `helpers` is not a good name directly under `site-packages`. Your project structure should be nested under a top-level package `rdfdf/__init__.py` with `helpers` in that directory, not a single `rdfdf.py` with `helpers` floating directly under `site-packages`.

Comment: @dROOOze interesting, thanks! I just recently started using poetry, so I'll have to look into this!

Comment: @dROOOze true, the package structure is not done properly, I already started doing this properly in recent projects, but right now I'm too afraid to change anything because `ModuleNotFoundErrors` literally haunt me lol. Will have to change the structure soon though.

Comment: The `src/` directory structure is very popular in the Python community, maybe this will help: https://browniebroke.com/blog/convert-existing-poetry-to-src-layout/

Comment: @MichaelButscher @dROOze I changed the directory structure in the hope that this might fix the problem; but again I see the `ModuleNotFoundError`.. Could somebody maybe have another look?